# Initializing metatrader in python

Tags: python, algorithm, metatrader5

I am trying to use the Metatrader library to extract market data and build algorithms.
The first lines to get started with this library just don't work

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
mt5.initialize()
```

These lines of code always return an output of **False** meaning that mt5 has not initialized, i have not seen this issue addressed anywhere else so i would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 6):

You need to precise your login, your password, your server and download the MetaTrader 5 terminal EXE file() in order to connect to Metatrader.

> ```
> if not mt5.initialize(login=25115284, server="MetaQuotes-Demo",password="4zatlbqx"):
>     print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
>     quit()
> ```

(cf. https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5initialize_py)

You should also take a look at the `last_error()` section (https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5lasterror_py) of the Metatrader documentation and install Metatrader if it's not already https://www.metatrader5.com/en/automated-trading